# Newline not preserved when markdown text is stored in firestore field

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Wrote a markdown text using https://stackedit.io, copied the markdown output, and pasted it into a Firestore field to be rendered in my android app using the [markwon](https://github.com/noties/Markwon) library.

However, I noticed that the text from Firestore did not render properly on the android but the raw markdown text when used directly on the app rendered well. After investigation,  discovered that Firestore stripes all the new line in the markdown text and only displays a large text without new line or line break.

What I have tried:

1. I have tried to replace `\\n` character with `\n` before rendering - Did not work
2. Manually add \n character in the firestore text - Did not work
3. Converted the markdown to html before storing in firestore - Worked but not sustainable and didn't give desired output

How do I fix this ssue such that the markdown text in firestore is rendered correctly on android?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not support escape sequences in string values. It simply does not understand any sort of escape sequences that might have a special meaning in a particular programming language.

This means that if you write "\n" in a string-type field, and later when you want to read it, you'll read exactly that backslash and the `n` character. If you need to store special escape sequences like `\n` or `\\n`, then you consider encoding and decoding that yourself.